# I have an error while using font awesome library downloadable font

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome library in my project but there are an error while using it `downloadable font: download failed The Error Image

[image: 1]

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0): status=2147746065 source: http://127.0.0.1:5500/To%20Do%20List/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2

I'm trying to solve this problem

Comment: Try loading it over https.